# php file upload: how to change the word 'browse' in the button?

Tags: php, file-upload

I follow the instruction of http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to upload a file.

I need to translate this part into other languages, depending in which language the page is displayed. I cannot find where the word 'browse' for the file name comes from and how to change it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that is set by the browser API itself.  Meaning, the word "Browse", will be local to whatever language the user is using.  So you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the wording but it's more of a CSS trick than anything. Have a look at this link:

[Custom File Input Styling in WebKit/Blink](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/)

I prefer to use the bootstrap method outlined here:

[Whipping File Inputs Into Shape with Bootstrap 3](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/)

Comment: Nice One. Till Date, I was thinking that it can't be changed. Nice Work.